# How do I iterate over my linked list to search for and delete specific strings?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

This method works fine when I try to delete a single item, but when I'm using a file to delete multiple items i get a concurrent modification exception.

```
    static void delete(String dString) {
    LinkedList<String> AddressBook2 = AddressBook;
    for(String s : AddressBook2){
        String subString = dString.toUpperCase().substring(7);
        if(s.toUpperCase().contains(subString)){
            AddressBook.remove(s);
            System.out.println("Removal Successful: "+ s);

        }

    }

    System.out.println("ERROR: Not found for Removal: "+dString.substring(7));
    System.out.println("----------------------------");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an iterator to safe remove element, like:

```
String subString = dString.toUpperCase().substring(7);

boolean resultFound = false;

for (Iterator<String> iterator = addressBook2.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String s = iterator.next();
    if(s.toUpperCase().contains(subString)) { 
        iterator.remove(); 
        System.out.println("Removal Successful: "+ s); 
        resultFound = true;
    } 
}

if (!resultFound) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: Not found for Removal: "+dString.substring(7));
}
System.out.println("----------------------------");
```

One more, you don't need to get substring on every loop iteration, so I moved it out of for statement. And you have to provide some logic, to make your message `ERROR: Not found for Removal:` happens only if nothing really found. I've made it with boolean flag as the example.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thanks!